# List comprehension in typing.Union

Tags: python-3.x, typing

Rather than write out all the combinations, I've tried the following:

```
from typing import Union, Tuple
from itertools import product as prod

class A: pass
v = (A, None)

annot = Union[Tuple[x, y] for x, y in prod(v, v)] # breaks ofc
```

Obviously this breaks because I'm trying to treat it like a list comprehension. Doing the following (which is similar to the above anyway) breaks also:

```
X = [Tuple[x, y] for x, y in prod(v, v)]
Union[X]     # breaks
Union[*X]    # also breaks
Union[*[X]]  # breaks again
```

But is there *some way* of doing this?

Just for clarity, the end result I want is:

```
Union[Tuple[A, A], Tuple[A, NoneType], Tuple[NoneType, A], Tuple[NoneType, NoneType]]
```

Comment: Even if you write up something that evaluates the same at runtime, it's unlikely the static analyzers will understand it, and static analysis is currently the main use case of type annotations.

Comment: @user2357112 I suppose that makes sense enough. It was just a thought (trying to save a little horizontal space).

Comment: That said, it seems like `Tuple[Optional[A], Optional[A]]` might be more appropriate for your use case than the 4-way Union you're trying to use.

Comment: did you find a way for this? If not it's a shame this isn't possible. You can do this in JS with https://flow.org/ and it is super handy :)

Answer (score 0):

The Python tuple unpacking can do the trick, to keep the different, "meta"-level semantics of `[` and `]` in the context of `typing.Union[expression]` unaffected.

So try this:

annot = Union[`*tuple(`Tuple[x, y] for x, y in prod(v, v)`)`]

We basically create a tuple out of your Python generator-comprehension expression, and then we unpack it and feed it into `Union[expr]`.

Actually, the `tuple` word can be removed, and leave only `*(` and `)`.

I had a rather similar need as the OP, when I needed to generate OpenAPI documentation for a microservice Web API implemented in FastAPI and Pydantic, for a "simple" Python `enum.IntEnum` type. Like this:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Literal, Union
from enum import IntEnum, unique

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

@unique
class SessionStatus(IntEnum):
    """
    SessionStatus enum type
    """
    Stopped = 0
    WaitingForServer = 1
    WaitingForClient = 2
    Started = 3

class Session(BaseModel):
    """
    Session DTO
    """

    status: Annotated[
        Union[*(Annotated[Literal[kvp.value], Field(description=kvp.name)] for kvp in SessionStatus)],
        Field(title="status", description="## Session status")
    ]


My OpenAPI JSON schema outcome then looked like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVkmx.png
```